# How can I publish a new developer portal when it's behind a virtual network?

Tags: networking, azure, private

I'm trying to access a new project from within the associated virtual network. The url looks something like https://myexample.developer.azure-api.net/ and when I navigate there from within a machine on the vnet, I get a page that says:

> This is a home page of the Developer portal - an automatically generated, fully customizable website for publishing your API documentation where consumers can discover APIs, learn how to use them, request access, and try them out.
>
> The content hasn't been published yet. You can do so in "Developer portal" section of your API Management Service in the Azure portal. Learn more.

So I go to publish the page from the Azure Portal on my local/physical machine, except the portal is telling me

> You can't publish the developer portal, because connection to the portal couldn't be established. This may happen if your API Management service is in an internal virtual network and the network configuration prevents the connection or if the DNS resolution fails. Use button above to open Developer portal and follow this guidance to publish Developer portal

How do you publish it? I recognize that my physical machine isn't on the network but how else could I access the Azure Portal in order to publish it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you're logged into the Azure Portal site from a machine that's within the actual virtual network.

For example, even though you may be able to access and configure resources in Azure Portal from your "main physical machine" that isn't on the virtual network, **publishing itself must be done from a machine that's within the vnet.**

So either allow your physical machine into the network or simply remote into the VM that's configured within the vnet and publish your project from https://portal.azure.com. Sometimes the "Publish" button can still be greyed out but clicking "Developer portal" in the top left (from the **Portal Overview**) and publishing from the developer site seems to fix it.